# Convert Points to textual representation

Tags: java, string, point

Let's say I have two Points

```
new Point(80,40);
new Point(40,80);
```

And I want to convert them to end up as one string, a String representation.

```
01
10
```

Where 1 is a point, and 0 is empty space. You can see here that the string is magnified 40x, and each point has a width and height of 40. All points will be multiples of 40.

I tried to make something up with StringBuilder but I don't know where to start, given that I can only insert a character given the length of a string, not the height(or y value).

Here is a another example.

```
 new Point(120,80);
 new Point(80,240);
 new Point(40,80);
```

turns into

```
 010
 001
 000
 000
 000
 010
```

I would preferably like a solution that is efficient, I have thousands of Points. No code is required for a solution, just an idea of how this might be implemented.

However, data is actually stored in a hashmap containing the character that is supposed to be written(in the above example all 1) as the key and the point as the value.

Example for Hashmap

```
     Value             Key
 new Point(40,40)      'a'
 new Point(80,80)      'b'
```

Which would result in

```
 a0
 0b
```

Comment: What kind of datatype are these keys?

Comment: then take a 2D char array instead of a 2D boolean array and initialize it with '0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses memory, but is nevertheless computationally efficient:

1. Create a 2D boolean array to represent your "map", initialized to all-`false`.
2. Iterate through your points, divide coordinates by 40, use this to index into the array, and set to `true`.
3. Iterate over your 2D array, printing `1` or `0` for each element.

Comment: Yes, that would work, given there are only 2 values for the points. However, there are not. I will update question shortly. Thank you for the idea though.

Comment: @user2097804: Ok, I've seen your update.  But that's a trivial modification to my proposal, store a 2D array of `char` instead.